# Xcode build settings - how to capitalize a variable

Tags: xcode, xcode-build-settings

Inside xcode build settings we can define some custom value. I would define a custom LaunchScreen value based on my current scheme (flavor).
I'm looking for a way to capitalize the bundle identifier value (put the first letter in upper case). I can put all the value in lower (:lower) or upper (:upper) case.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever manage to make this work?

Comment: No, i did an other way to handle that with extra custom defined variable. Little sad but yep that work...